# Replace NaN with column value on a row by row basis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In my Pandas DataFrame I'd like to replace all instances of NaN (np.nan) on a row by row basis with the corresponding value from column "E".

This DataFrame here..

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 3 | NaN | 88 |
| NaN | 5 | NaN | 4 | 55 |

should result in..

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 88 | 3 | 88 | 88 |
| 55 | 5 | 55 | 4 | 55 |

I cannot find any code to solve this issue.

Data:

```
{'A': [1, nan],
 'B': [nan, 5],
 'C': [3, nan],
 'D': [nan, 4],
 'E': [88, 55]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transpose + `fillna` + transpose back:

```
df = df.T.fillna(df['E']).T.astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1  88   3  88  88
1  55   5  55   4  55
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `mask`

```
df = df.mask(df.isna(),df['E'],axis=0)
Out[423]: 
      A     B     C     D   E
0   1.0  88.0   3.0  88.0  88
1  55.0   5.0  55.0   4.0  55
```

Answer (score 0):

this works as well:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x['E']), axis=1)
```